# How to find length of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

Consider the following code. How can I find the length of size. 
When doing `size.length` it gives undefined.

```
var size= arr2[3].Operator;
```

size value is :

```
DT3702: Object
DT3703: Object
DT3704: Object
DT3705: Object
DT3706: Object
DT3707: Object
DT3708: Object
```

The value of `arr2[3]` is :

```
Operator: Object
  DT3702: Object
  DT3703: Object
  DT3704: Object
  DT3705: Object
  DT3706: Object
  DT3707: Object
  DT3708: Object
```

After taking length why is this line throwing error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`:

```
 var dataArray2 = [['TruckName', 'OperatorName']];
 for (var i = 3; i < arr2.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < length; j++){
     dataArray2.push([arr2[i].Operator[j].Object, arr2[i].Operator[j].name]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: looks like `size` is an object not an array... in that case you can try to use `Object.keys(size).length`(check browser support)... or you need to iterate through each property of the object and find its length

Comment: @ArunPJohny Please check the updated issue.

Comment: Operator seems not an array, so you call xxx.Operator[j] is undefined.

Comment: @mrmoment Operator is indeed not an array, but what is the solution to it.

Comment: @NagendraSingh You need to list the structure of Operator. Typically, call the member of the Operator object like Operator.memberName.

Comment: @mrmoment Yes I tried that, But that would exclude my DT370* numbers. Right? I need that DT370* values also to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var length = 0;
for(var obj in arr2[3].Operator){
  length++;
}
```

Ok try something like the above. This will count the number of sub properties on Operator.

Comment: I need the third element of the `arr2` object. So when I do `arr2[3].length`. It still gives undefined.

Comment: What is your definition of length for this object?

Comment: I have updated an issue after updating the length value, Please check.

Comment: Operator is not an array, so you can't index it like that. My loop just counts the number of child objects on the operator object by enumerating the properties on the object.

Answer (score 0):

For your updated question, you need to display the key set of an object. You can try `Object.keys(obj)`. In your case `obj` is the `Operator` object. This will return you an array. And you can get each of the array elements by square brackets.